# Python scraper regex that allows spaces and periods

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a python scraper using regex that allows both spaces and periods.

I am trying to get baseball team names from a certain site so some are `Miami` (full words) but others are `San Francisco` (with spaces) and others are `Chi. Cubs` (period and space).

I know the pattern before the city name and I know the pattern name after, I am trying to find something that just matches everything between, regardless of number of charecters or spaces or periods.  I would prefer to use regex, but if its way easier to use a different library I am open to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a regex to match any number of spaces, periods, or letters:

```
[ .a-zA-Z]+
```

Examples:

```
>>> re.search(r'[ .a-zA-Z]+', 'Miami').group(0)
'Miami'
>>> re.search(r'[ .a-zA-Z]+', 'San Francisco').group(0)
'San Francisco'
>>> re.search(r'[ .a-zA-Z]+', 'Chi. Cubs').group(0)
'Chi. Cubs'
```

Comment: You need to escape the period, i.e. `\.` as right now it matches any character.

Comment: @Junuxx - `.` does not have a special meaning inside of a character class, so escaping it is not necessary in this regex.

Comment: games = re.findall(team_tool + '[ .a-zA-z]', site)
team_tool and site are both variables, and this only returned the first letter of each city

Comment: i am trying to get all the teams scrapped into a list, where the order i get them matters

Comment: @Tom, I see you have trouble copying and pasting.